# Pandas Json : "TypeError: to_json() got an unexpected keyword argument 'indent' "

Tags: python, pandas

Using this simple piece of code, i'm getting an error.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]],
    index=["row 1", "row 2"],
    columns=["col 1", "col 2"],
)

result = df.to_json(orient="split",indent=None)
```

I am getting this error :
"TypeError: to_json() got an unexpected keyword argument 'indent' "

But in the documentation, it seems pretty clear that it is one of the parameter possible.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

Do you know what is happening here? Or i don't know how to read documentation. Thank you!

Comment: What version are you using? print(pd.__version__)

Comment: "New in version 1.0.0". What version do you have?

Comment: ah sorry, i have version 0.24.2. Should i delete the question or answer to my own question? this is funny i have done pip install pandas